# lucene / solr remove common phrases (stop phrases)

Tags: lucene, solr, full-text-search

I would like to eliminate from the search query the words/phrases that bring no meaning to the query (we could call them stop phrases). Example:

"How to .."

"Where can I find .."

"What is the meaning of .."

etc.

1. Where to find / how to compute a list of 'common phrases' for English and for French?
2. How to implement it in Solr (Is there anything more advanced than the stopwords feature?)

Comment: It is just a link. Maybe you need a more accurate, exact solution

http://armandbrahaj.blog.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/

Comment: 10x for the tip. However, I'm interested in solutions other than basic stopwords feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you shouldn't try to completely get rid of these phrases, because they reveal intent of the searcher. You can try to leverage the existence of them by using a natural language question answering system like [Ephyra](http://www.ephyra.info/). There is even a [project](http://code.google.com/p/natural-language-qa/) aimed at integration of it with Lucene. I haven't used it myself, but maybe at least evaluating it is 
worth a try.

If you are determined to remove them, then I think that you need to write custom [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) that will filter the query, delegating the further processing to a parser of your choice.